# Creating Custom Paper Size in Javafx 11+

Tags: printing, javafx-11

I am trying to create a custom Paper size in JavaFX 12.

The older method would require using the `PrintHelper` class and the `Units` class which exists in the package `com.sun.javafx.print`. However in a JavaFX 11+, this package is not exported and as a result I cannot use these classes.

What are the alternatives to this classes in JavaFX 11+ ? every time I search I get the result from JavaFX 8, which are not helpful in the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Thank to you , your post has steered me to the right direction .
I suppose , to create a new `Paper` , you are going to use `PrintHelper.createPaper(String , double , double , Units)` to access the private constructor of `Paper`.

However, somewhere along the way , we got the message:

```
class YourClass (in unnamed module @0x2feb050e) cannot access
  class com.sun.javafx.print.Units (in module javafx.graphics)
  because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.print
  to unnamed module @0x2feb050e
```

By simply adding `--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.print=ALL-UNNAMED` into VM option should fix the problem .

hope that I am not too late to answer your question .